# Updating an app that did not previously have a database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an Android app that mainly used the SharedPreferences to save data. I recently replaced that whole structure with an SQLite database instead. The problem is I published the app before even adding the database file or any of the database helper classes to the project. I was just wondering if these changes would integrate smoothly with the older version of the app.

Comment: okay,you can use the onCreate method in sqlitehelper class to copy all your sharedpreference data to the DB after creation of database.

Comment: @s.shivasurya Actually I'm not too concerned with migrating the data to the database - I was more wondering if there was anything special I needed to do to make older versions of the app recognize the newly added database.

Comment: How would it be even possible to have an old app with the new database?

Comment: @CL. The old version app did not use a database at all, so there was no .db file packaged with it.

Comment: And if the DB file is not packaged, how would the old app be able to access it?

Comment: @CL. Sorry, I'm not following? The first version of my app was not packaged with a .db file, meaning it wasn't making any database queries and was not accessing anything. I published that first version without any problems. It's only recently when I decided that I'd like my app to store some data in a database. So on my local copy I added a .db file, created the relevant helper classes, etc. I have no real issues on my local copy either. The problem is if I publish this newer version, would it cause any issues for people who have the old version installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an app is updated, the old code is replaced with the new code. So the old version of the app will never see a DB file.

Comment: But then why is that we have to specify database versions in the SQLiteAssetHelper class? If the code was being replaced, wouldn't the database be recreated from scratch each time?

Comment: The *code* is replaced, but not the *data*. Database versions help with updating databases.